# How to count rows in nested tables with one SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables. Each `User` can have multiple `Subscriptions`  and each `Subscription` can have multiple `Payments`.

Me goal is to count all `Payments` for a single `User` using one SQL query. Is it possible to do and how?

In the case below, The result for a `User` with `id 1` should be **2** (because the `User` has two `Payments`)

```
Users
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+
| 1  | John |
+----+------+

Subscriptions
+----+--------+-----------+
| Id | userId |   data    |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 1  |   1    | some data |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 2  |   1    | some data |
+----+--------+-----------+

Payments

+----+----------------+--------+
| Id | subscriptionId | amount |
+----+----------------+--------+
| 1  |        1       |   30   |
+----+----------------+--------+
|  2 |        2       |   50   |
+----+----------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like below by using join and aggregation

```
SELECT u.id, u.Name, COUNT(p.id) AS numberofpayment
FROM users u
  Left JOIN Subscriptions s ON u.Id=s.userId
  Left JOIN Payments p ON s.id=p.subscriptionId
GROUP BY u.id, u.Name
```

Comment: Might be best to use LEFT OUTER JOINs to allow a count of 0 when the user exists but has no payments.

Comment: @Kickstart This answer is good to count all Payments for a single User.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak - if the user has no subscriptions or no payments the query as it stands will return no rows, rather than a row for the user with a count of 0.

Comment: @Kickstart Yes, true... It's better to use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Hey guys thanks I edited you are right left is more meaningful

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.Id) AS PaymentCount
FROM Users u
  LEFT JOIN Subscriptions s ON u.Id=s.userId
  LEFT JOIN Payments p ON s.id=p.subscriptionId
WHERE u.Id = @yourUserID
```

Pay attention on `COUNT(p.Id)` - it means count of existing payments.

PS: this answer for @Kickstart.